# New operator breaks firebase set

Tags: javascript, firebase

Before reading on, realize that I already know the fix to my problem. But don't understand why it works and I could really use some clarification.

So I'm trying to create an object as soon as the user authenticates. So I can associate methods with that object (ex: delete the users node when the the browser is closed) but encountered a very weird issue.

First of all, as soon as the user authenticates I create a new object like so

```
 user = new handleData(authData.uid, authData.google.displayName, authData.google.profileImageURL);
```

my handleData constructor looks a bit like this

```
function handleData(){
    this.uid = arguments[0];
    this.name = arguments[1];
    this.profilePicture = arguments[2];

    var userNode = "users/{0}".format(this.uid);

    var data = {
        name : this.name,
        profilePicture : this.profilePicture
    }

    //Doesnt work code
    myDatabase.child(userNode).set({
        name: this.name,
        profilePicture : this.profilePicture
    });
    //Works
    myDatabase.child(userNode).set(data);
};
```

Firebase throws this error when I try the first child .set({})

[image: firebase set error]

Script:455 is the first line after the //Doesnt work comment in my snippet.
If I just set an object (data) then my code just works without issues which is weird because they are identically the same.

Also I want to mention that, if I just call my functions without the new operator, the code just works. So what is the new operator doing that breaks my code?

Comment: Those two things you posted are exactly equivalent. The error you've got suggests that you're actually doing something like `{[this.profilePicture]: undefined}`

Comment: But I am obviously not doing that ? Its really confusing

Comment: Are you sure the `set` call is not inside of some callback? Is this your complete and exact code?

Comment: My set is in two callbacks, but console logging ""this.name" & "this.profilePicture" gives me the appropriate values. Do you this this is just a pointer issue ? Also if you want complete and exact code checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/087a19th/) Problem occurs at line 47

Comment: No, logging `this.name` in that location won't give you the appropriate values either.

Comment: @bergi I think the pointers are just pointing to someone else. Instead of using pointers all over my function. I decided to assign them to a local variable at the start of my function so that I can properly refer to them later on.